# Crear un inventario usando python que lo guarde en un excel

Tags: python, excel, diccionarios

Hola buenas noches, es mi primer pregunta, debo crear un programa en python que genera un archivo de Excel (con nombre inventario.xlsx) esta parte me genera error

> 2. Presente un menú al usuario para que pueda realizar las siguientes funcionalidades. (Listo)
>
> a. Ingresar artículos nuevos: Esta función debe permitir ingresar un nuevo articulo con todos sus valores. Verifique el que número de código no esté ingresado antes. (Listo)
>
> b. Modificar articulo: Esta función permite que, dado un articulo el usuario modifique alguno de sus valores.  (Listo)
>
> c. Imprimir Inventario: Se despliega la información de los elementos del inventario. (Listo)
>
> d. Compra de Productos: El sistema permite que se seleccionen varios productos a comprar y la cantidad de cada uno de ellos. Debe verificar que haya la cantidad disponibles. (Listo)
>
> > i.    Una vez dichos los artículos debe desplegar el valor total para cada articulo (Listo)
> >
> > ii.   Modificar la cantidad de artículos del inventario.  (Listo)
>
> e. Salir. (Listo) **pero no logró guardarlo en el excel**
>
> 3. Cuando el usuario escoge Salir. La información final debe actualizarse en el archivo Excel.

Cualquier ayuda será de gran utilidad, muchas gracias

```
import openpyxl
    
    ListaProducto=[]
    VectorProducto=[]
    Vector=[]
     
    >usamos para ver si el vector se encuentra vacío o lleno mediante 
    def Buscar(Codigo):
        Posicion=len(ListaProducto)
        return Posicion
 

    >Buscamos el nombre del producto a consultar
    def BuscarNombre(Codigo):
        Posicion=len(ListaProducto)
        if Posicion==0:
            Nombre=''
        else:
            for VectorProducto in ListaProducto:
                if VectorProducto[0]==Codigo:
                    Nombre=VectorProducto[1]
                else:
                    Nombre=''
        return Nombre
     
    >Extraemos todos los datos del producto a buscar
    def BuscarProducto(Codigo):
        VPRODUCTO=[]
        for VectorProducto in ListaProducto:
            if VectorProducto[0]==Codigo:
                VPRODUCTO.append(VectorProducto[0])
                VPRODUCTO.append(VectorProducto[1])
                VPRODUCTO.append(VectorProducto[2])
                VPRODUCTO.append(VectorProducto[3])
                VPRODUCTO.append(VectorProducto[4])
        return VPRODUCTO
     
    >Mostramos los datos del producto buscado
    def BuscarProducto2(Codigo):
        VPRODUCTO=[]
        for VPRODUCTO in ListaProducto:
            if VPRODUCTO[0]==Codigo:
                print("Codigo: ",VPRODUCTO[0])
                print("Nombre: ",VPRODUCTO[1])
                print("Saldo Disponible: ",VPRODUCTO[2])
                print("Costo Promedio: ",VPRODUCTO[3])
                print("Total: ",VPRODUCTO[4])
     
    >Actualizamos el Saldo del Producto deacuerdo al movimiento (Ingreso/Egreso)
    def existencia(Codigo,TipoMov,Cantidad,Total):
        VPRODUCTO=[]
        for VectorProducto in ListaProducto:
            if VectorProducto[0]==Codigo:
                ListaProducto.remove(VectorProducto)
                CantidadT=float(VectorProducto[2])
                TotalT=float(VectorProducto[4])
                if TipoMov=='I':
                    CantidadT=CantidadT+float(Cantidad)
                    TotalT=TotalT+float(Total)
                    print('I',CantidadT)
                    print('I',TotalT)
                else:
                    CantidadT=CantidadT-float(Cantidad)
                    TotalT=TotalT-float(Total)
                    print('E',CantidadT)
                    print('E',TotalT)
                if CantidadT==0:
                    Costo=0
                else:
                    Costo=TotalT/CantidadT
                VPRODUCTO.append(VectorProducto[0])
                VPRODUCTO.append(VectorProducto[1])
                VPRODUCTO.append(CantidadT)
                VPRODUCTO.append(Costo)
                VPRODUCTO.append(TotalT)
                ListaProducto.append(VPRODUCTO)
     
    >Realizamos el Ingreso de Producto
    def Ingreso():
        print('')
        print('****** INGRESO DE PRODUCTO ******')
        Codigo=input("Ingrese el Código del Producto: ")
        Nombre=BuscarNombre(Codigo)
        if Nombre=='':
            Nombre=input("Ingrese la Descripción del Producto: ")
        else:
            Nombre=BuscarNombre(Codigo)
            print("Nombre del Producto: ",Nombre)
        Cantidad=input("Ingrese la Cantidad del Producto: ")
        Precio=input("Ingrese el Precio Unitario: ")
        Total=float(Cantidad)*float(Precio)
        Orden=input("Ingrese el N° de Orden de Compra: ")
        if Buscar(Codigo)==0:
            VectorProducto.append(Codigo)
            VectorProducto.append(Nombre)
            VectorProducto.append(Cantidad)
            VectorProducto.append(Precio)
            VectorProducto.append(Total)
            ListaProducto.append(VectorProducto)
        else:
            print(existencia(Codigo,'I',Cantidad,Total))   
        print('')
     
    >Realizamos el Egreso (Venta)
    def Egreso():  
        print('')
        print('****** EGRESO DE PRODUCTO ******')
        Codigo=input("Ingrese el Código del Producto: ")
        Vector=BuscarProducto(Codigo)
        if len(Vector)>0:
            print("Nombre del Producto: ",Vector[1])
            print("Costo del Producto: ",Vector[3])
            Cantidad=float(input("Ingrese la Cantidad a Egresar: "))
            Total=float(Vector[3])*Cantidad
            Orden=input("Ingrese el N° de Factura: ")
         
            print('')
        else:
            print("¡Producto No Existe!")
    
    >Aquí me da el error, si quito la sección de excel el programa corre, esta sección
    >es la que necesito para guardarlo en un excel
    file = openpyxl.Workbook()
    hoja= file.active
    hoja.cell(row= 1, column= 1, value= "Producto")
    hoja.cell(row= 1, column= 2, value= "Cantidad")
    hoja.cell(row= 1, column= 3, value= "Valor")
    hoja.cell(row= 1, column= 4, value= "Egreso")
    
    row = 2
    for key, value in Ingreso.items():
        hoja.cell(row=row, column= 1, value=key)
        hoja.cell(row=row, column= 2, value=value[0])
        hoja.cell(row=row, column= 3, value=value[1])
        hoja.cell(row=row, column= 4, value=value[2])
        row += 1
    
    for key, value in Egreso.items():
        hoja.cell(row=row, column= 1, value=key)
        hoja.cell(row=row, column= 2, value=value[0])
        hoja.cell(row=row, column= 3, value=value[1])
        hoja.cell(row=row, column= 4, value=value[2])
        row += 1
    
    for key, value in existencia.items():
        hoja.cell(row=row, column= 1, value=key)
        hoja.cell(row=row, column= 2, value=value[0])
        hoja.cell(row=row, column= 3, value=value[1])
        hoja.cell(row=row, column= 4, value=value[2])
        row += 1
    
    file.save("inventario.xlsx")
    file.close()
      
    >Menú Principal
    while True:
        print('SISTEMA DE INVENTARIO')
        print('')
        print('****** Menú Principal ******')
        print('0. SALIR')
        print('1. INGRESO DE PRODUCTO')
        print('2. EGRESO DE PRODUCTO')
        print('3. BUSQUEDA DE PRODUCTO')
        opcion=input('Digitar una Opción: ')
        if opcion=='0':
            break
        elif opcion=='1':
            Ingreso()
        elif opcion=='2':
            Egreso()
        elif opcion=='3':
            print('')
            print('****** BUSQUEDA DE PRODUCTO ******')
            Codigo=input("Ingrese el código del Producto: ")
            BuscarProducto2(Codigo)
        else:
            print('Opción no válida')
```

Comment: Y ¿cuál  es el problema que tienes?

Comment: Hola gracias, la parte de excel es la que me da error, no logró hacer que guarde el inventario en un excel

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask]. En tu pregunta debes mencionar cuál es el problema _en específico_ que estás teniendo. Tal como está, pareciera que quieres que hagan el trabajo por ti. Pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles, y describe el error concreto que estás teniendo.

Answer (score 0):

Primero para el futuro, en especial en Python, vigila los tabuladores, al subir el código son importantes para poder replicar y entender bien tu programa.

Segundo, evite usar palabras reservadas, por ejemplo value puede sustituirlo por valor su traducción.

Tercero, en caso de que el apartado del excel vaya fuera de la función Egreso
para que se ejecute al salir y no al principio tendría que estar invertido o tener otra función para ello.

Cuarto, no entiendo el ingreso.Items(), egreso.items(),etc  de los for, ¿falta algún código que no hayas subido? Me saca error por ellos, he supuesto que lo que quieres imprimir en el excel es la lista de productos que tienes declarada.

Quinto hablas de diccionarios en los tag, pero yo solo veo una listas dentro de otra lista.
El resultado funcional es el siguiente:

```
import openpyxl
    
ListaProducto=[]
VectorProducto=[]
Vector=[]
     
    #usamos para ver si el vector se encuentra vacío o lleno mediante 
def Buscar(Codigo):
        Posicion=len(ListaProducto)
        return Posicion
 

    #Buscamos el nombre del producto a consultar
def BuscarNombre(Codigo):
        Posicion=len(ListaProducto)
        if Posicion==0:
            Nombre=''
        else:
            for VectorProducto in ListaProducto:
                if VectorProducto[0]==Codigo:
                    Nombre=VectorProducto[1]
                else:
                    Nombre=''
        return Nombre
     
    #Extraemos todos los datos del producto a buscar
def BuscarProducto(Codigo):
        VPRODUCTO=[]
        for VectorProducto in ListaProducto:
            if VectorProducto[0]==Codigo:
                VPRODUCTO.append(VectorProducto[0])
                VPRODUCTO.append(VectorProducto[1])
                VPRODUCTO.append(VectorProducto[2])
                VPRODUCTO.append(VectorProducto[3])
                VPRODUCTO.append(VectorProducto[4])
        return VPRODUCTO
     
    #Mostramos los datos del producto buscado
def BuscarProducto2(Codigo):
        VPRODUCTO=[]
        for VPRODUCTO in ListaProducto:
            if VPRODUCTO[0]==Codigo:
                print("Codigo: ",VPRODUCTO[0])
                print("Nombre: ",VPRODUCTO[1])
                print("Saldo Disponible: ",VPRODUCTO[2])
                print("Costo Promedio: ",VPRODUCTO[3])
                print("Total: ",VPRODUCTO[4])
     
    #Actualizamos el Saldo del Producto deacuerdo al movimiento (Ingreso/Egreso)
def existencia(Codigo,TipoMov,Cantidad,Total):
        VPRODUCTO=[]
        for VectorProducto in ListaProducto:
            if VectorProducto[0]==Codigo:
                ListaProducto.remove(VectorProducto)
                CantidadT=float(VectorProducto[2])
                TotalT=float(VectorProducto[4])
                if TipoMov=='I':
                    CantidadT=CantidadT+float(Cantidad)
                    TotalT=TotalT+float(Total)
                    print('I',CantidadT)
                    print('I',TotalT)
                else:
                    CantidadT=CantidadT-float(Cantidad)
                    TotalT=TotalT-float(Total)
                    print('E',CantidadT)
                    print('E',TotalT)
                if CantidadT==0:
                    Costo=0
                else:
                    Costo=TotalT/CantidadT
                VPRODUCTO.append(VectorProducto[0])
                VPRODUCTO.append(VectorProducto[1])
                VPRODUCTO.append(CantidadT)
                VPRODUCTO.append(Costo)
                VPRODUCTO.append(TotalT)
                ListaProducto.append(VPRODUCTO)
     
    #Realizamos el Ingreso de Producto
def Ingreso():
        print('')
        print('****** INGRESO DE PRODUCTO ******')
        Codigo=input("Ingrese el Código del Producto: ")
        Nombre=BuscarNombre(Codigo)
        if Nombre=='':
            Nombre=input("Ingrese la Descripción del Producto: ")
        else:
            Nombre=BuscarNombre(Codigo)
            print("Nombre del Producto: ",Nombre)
        Cantidad=input("Ingrese la Cantidad del Producto: ")
        Precio=input("Ingrese el Precio Unitario: ")
        Total=float(Cantidad)*float(Precio)
        Orden=input("Ingrese el N° de Orden de Compra: ")
        if Buscar(Codigo)==0:
            VectorProducto.append(Codigo)
            VectorProducto.append(Nombre)
            VectorProducto.append(Cantidad)
            VectorProducto.append(Precio)
            VectorProducto.append(Total)
            ListaProducto.append(VectorProducto)
        else:
            print(existencia(Codigo,'I',Cantidad,Total))   
        print('')
     
    #Realizamos el Egreso (Venta)
def Egreso():  
        print('')
        print('****** REGRESO DE PRODUCTO ******')
        Codigo=input("Ingrese el Código del Producto: ")
        Vector=BuscarProducto(Codigo)
        if len(Vector)>0:
            print("Nombre del Producto: ",Vector[1])
            print("Costo del Producto: ",Vector[3])
            Cantidad=float(input("Ingrese la Cantidad a Egresar: "))
            Total=float(Vector[3])*Cantidad
            Orden=input("Ingrese el N° de Factura: ")
         
            print('')
        else:
            print("¡Producto No Existe!")
    
 
      
    #Menú Principal
while True:
        print('SISTEMA DE INVENTARIO')
        print('')
        print('****** Menú Principal ******')
        print('0. SALIR')
        print('1. INGRESO DE PRODUCTO')
        print('2. EGRESO DE PRODUCTO')
        print('3. BUSQUEDA DE PRODUCTO')
        opcion=input('Digitar una Opción: ')
        if opcion=='0':
            break
        elif opcion=='1':
            Ingreso()
        elif opcion=='2':
            Egreso()
        elif opcion=='3':
            print('')
            print('****** BUSQUEDA DE PRODUCTO ******')
            Codigo=input("Ingrese el código del Producto: ")
            BuscarProducto2(Codigo)
        else:
            print('Opción no válida')

   #Aquí me da el error, si quito la sección de excel el programa corre, esta sección
    #es la que necesito para guardarlo en un excel
file = openpyxl.Workbook()
hoja= file.active
hoja.cell(row= 1, column= 1, value= "Producto")
hoja.cell(row= 1, column= 2, value= "Cantidad")
hoja.cell(row= 1, column= 3, value= "Valor")
hoja.cell(row= 1, column= 4, value= "Egreso")
        
row = 2
for valor in ListaProducto:
            hoja.cell(row=row, column= 1, value=valor[0])
            hoja.cell(row=row, column= 2, value=valor[1])
            hoja.cell(row=row, column= 3, value=valor[2])
            hoja.cell(row=row, column= 4, value=valor[3])
            row += 1
        

        
file.save("inventario.xlsx")
file.close()
```

Excel (valor inventado):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, de igual manera muchas gracias por las recomendaciones, ya con el ejercicio corriendo le hice varias correcciones al excel, y muy al pendinete de las recomendaciones, un abrazo :)